# How can I share library between two program in c

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, shared-libraries, cpu-cache

I want to use same library functions (i.e. OpenSSL library ) in two different programs in C for computation. How can I make sure that both program use a common library , means **only** one copy of library is loaded into **shared main memory** and both program access the library from that memory location for computation?

For example, when 1st program access the library for computation it is loaded into cache from main memory and when the 2nd program wants to access it later , it will access the data from cache ( already loaded by 1st program), **not** from main memory again.

I am using GCC under Linux. Any explanation or pointer will be highly appreciated .

Comment: Use shared libraries. Afterwards the OS is taking care of the rest.

Comment: use shared libraries, for more http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: Are you talking about code segment or data segment? Code segment is per-shared object, data segment is per-process, I suppose.

Comment: @ adrin , I want to do same computation of different data sets and that too in different program , but using same library.

Comment: This is what shared libraries are for.

Comment: thanks pmr, trilok. I am wondering how should I write a code where I can perform computation on different data sets present in different program and for computation purpose I will use common(OpenSSL) library.

Comment: You don't care in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Code gets shared by the operating system, not only of shared libraries but also of executables of the same binary — you don't have to do anything to have this feature.  It is part of the system's memory management.

Data will not get shared between the two processes.  You would need threads in one process to share data.  But unless you want that, just make sure both programs use exactly the same shared library file (.so file).  Normally you won't have to think about that; it only might be important if two programs use different *versions* of a library (they would not get shared of course).

Have a look at the output of `ldd /path/to/binary` to see which shared libraries are used by a binary.

Comment: `ldd` it's not 100% reliable on this, you need to know what `ldd` does to be able to interpret its own output. `ldd` is also influenced by the environment in which it runs, and that environment can be a totally different story from the one where your app will run.

Comment: Of course.  I didn't think of the possibility that OP might try to use a _different computer_ to find out which shared library his binary will use.  Does it make sense to mention that in my answer?  It seems so far-fetched to use a different machine that I think it is enough to have that considered in the comments here.

Comment: a different environment it's not a _different computer_, I don't think you know what `ldd` operates if you write that; that's really not the point.

Comment: I find it too obvious to write into the answer that the call to `ldd` should be done in the environment in which also the execution would take place (same computer, same user, same configuration).  I fail to understand in what aspect your objection differs from one stating that the use of `ls` or `du` or a similar Unix tool depends on a lot of things and may give different results in different situations.  Well, of course it does.  Stating the obvious won't make the answer any better.  But since this might go unnoticed by the future reader, I find it okay to have that stated in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Read Drepper's paper [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

To make one, compile your code as [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), e.g.

```
 gcc -c -fPIC -O -Wall src1.c -o src1.pic.o
 gcc -c -fPIC -O -Wall src2.c -o src2.pic.o
```

then link it into a shared object

```
 gcc -shared src1.pic.o src2.pic.o -lsome -o libfoo.so
```

<sup>you may link a shared library `-lsome` into another one `libfoo.so`</sup>

Internally, the dynamic linker [ld-linux.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) is using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (and will do some [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) at dynamic link time) and what matters are [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). The kernel will use the file system cache to avoid reading twice a shared library used by different processes. See also [linuxatemyram.com](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Use e.g. [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). See also [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Try

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

to understand the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) of the [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) used by the [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running that `cat` command; not everything of an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared library is shared between processes, only some segments, including the [text segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segment)...