# How Can I Write two program in C to make use of shared memory by common function/code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, operating-system, shared-memory

I have one program having matrix multiplication code and another program having both matrix multiplication(same as first program) and addition program. I want to implement / achieve shared memory page concepts for the common matrix multiplication code ( so that only one copy of that multiplication code is loaded into main memory in a 4K page).

How can I do that ?

Should I make them as shared library ?

Or

Should I declare and define both matrix multiplication and addition code in a separate file and then make that shared library and then use that shared library ? Will that guarantee ONLY one copy of multiplication code is loaded into memory ?

I am using gcc under linux.

Any help is highly appreciated .

Comment: Just make a shared library (.so) with the common code in it - that's all you need to do.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21457213/841108) to a very similar question

Comment: See `man 3 shm_open` and `man 2 mmap`. Basically you shm_open(), then get file descriptor with mmap() which you then, might for example, ftruncate() before you access it with strcpy() or something.